# How to prove $(1+i\tan(z))^{-2a} + (1-i\tan(z))^{-2a} = 2\cos(z)^{2a} \cos(2az)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Let $a \in \mathbb C$ and $|z| < \pi/4$. How to prove that

$$(1+i\tan(z))^{-2a} + (1-i\tan(z))^{-2a} = 2\cos(z)^{2a} \cos(2az)$$

assuming that we use the principal branch of the logarithm function to define the exponentiation.

This identity appears when dealing with hypergeometric functions (see [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4) for example).

If $a \in \mathbb Z$, it probably follows from well-known trigonometric identities. For example, the case $a = -1$ is equivalent to showing

$$1-\tan(z)^2 = \cos(z)^{-2}\cos(-2z)$$

which is easy to prove using the double-angle formula for the cosine.

For the general case, I don't really know how to proceed. Any help or reference is welcomed !

EDIT : I think the $|z| < \pi/4$ assumption comes from the fact that $\tan(z)$ maps biholomorphically the strip $\{ |\Re(z)| < \pi/4 \}$ to $B(0,1)$ and is only needed to make sense of the hypergeometric function. The proof provided below works whenever $|\Re(z)| < \pi/2$.

Comment: LHS can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{\cos^{-2a}(z)}\left(e^{-2aiz}+e^{2aiz}\right)$. Now apply the complex form of cosine, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathrm{Since}\:\mid{z}\mid<\frac{\pi}{\mathrm{4}}\:\mathrm{then}\:\mathrm{cos}\left({z}\right)\neq\mathrm{0} \\ $
$\left.\mathrm{Change:}\:\mathrm{tan}\left({z}\right)=\frac{\mathrm{sin}\left({z}\right)}{\mathrm{cos}\left({z}\right)}\:\mathrm{then}\:\mathrm{LHS}=\mathrm{cos}^{\mathrm{2}{a}} \left({z}\right)\left(\mathrm{cos}\left({z}\right)+{i}\mathrm{sin}\left({z}\right)\right)^{−\mathrm{2}{a}} +\left(\mathrm{cos}\left({z}\right)−{i}\mathrm{sin}\left({z}\right)\right)^{−\mathrm{2}{a}} \right) \\ $
$=\mathrm{cos}^{\mathrm{2}{a}} \left({z}\right)\left({e}^{−{i}\mathrm{2}{az}} +{e}^{{i}\mathrm{2}{az}} \right) \\ $
$=\mathrm{2cos}^{\mathrm{2}{a}} \left({z}\right)\frac{\left({e}^{−{i}\mathrm{2}{az}} +{e}^{{i}\mathrm{2}{az}} \right)}{\mathrm{2}}=\mathrm{2cos}^{\mathrm{2}{a}} \left({z}\right)\mathrm{cos}\left(\mathrm{2}{az}\right) \\ $